# Code works on Desktop and Android but not on Apple

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, debugging

Hey guys I am hoping someone can help me. I am trying to build out my first portfolio site and a memory match game i created is not working properly on IOS devices. I didn't really build it to be mobile optimized but it works on my desktop and my andriod perfectly fine. On IOS the cards rotate but do not flip properly. Can someone tell me what I need to fix? Code below

### HTML

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title> Memory Game </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 selection class= "title">Philadelphia Eagles Memory Match</h1>
    <section class="memory-game">
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="CarsonWentz">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/cw.png"
        alt="CarsonWentz"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="CarsonWentz"">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/cw.png"
        alt="CarsonWentz"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="CoreyClement">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/cc.png"
        alt="CoreyClement"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="CoreyClement">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/cc.png"
        alt="CoreyClement"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="NelsonAgholor">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/na.png"
        alt="NelsonAgholor"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="NelsonAgholor">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/na.png"
        alt="NelsonAgholor"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="NickFoles">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/nf.png"
        alt="NickFoles"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="NickFoles">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/nf.png"
        alt="NickFoles"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="FletcherCox">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/fc.png"
        alt="FletcherCox"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="FletcherCox">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/fc.png"
        alt="FletcherCox"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="ZachErtz">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/ze.png"
        alt="ZachErtz"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="ZachErtz">
        <img class="front-face" src="images/ze.png"
        alt="ZachErtz"/>
        <img class="back-face" src="images/eaglesfront.png"
        alt="PhillyEagles"/>
      </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

### CSS

```
 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background: #004C54;
}

h1 {
  color: #ACC0C6;
  text-align: center;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.memory-card {
  width:calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform.5s;
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #A5ACAF;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

#### JS

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;

function flipCard() {
  if(lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;
  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    //first click
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
  } else {
    //second click
    hasFlippedCard = false;
    secondCard = this;

    checkForMatch();
  }
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;

  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
    lockBoard = false;
  }, 1500);
}

function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard, lockBoard = [false, false];
  firstCard, secondCard = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

Comment: have you tired running this with chrome on ios ? :D

Comment: `<div class="memory-card" data-framework="CarsonWentz"">`, you added an extra `"` at the end. Remove it.

Comment: Yes chrome did the same thing